# How can I soften these edges?

Tags: modeling

I would like to soften the hard edges of this shape (the edges selected). I tried to extrude the edge and scaled it down but because edges are not on the same plane it doesn't work. Can't add loopcut too. Thanks .
PS this question is the following of "How can I keep hard edges with this shape?"
[image]

@Neil Giliomee thanks but unfortunately I cannot add a Loop Cut. Here what happens. Loop Cuts don't reproduce the shape of the edges.

[image]
[image]

The result after having applied two Loop Cuts.
[image]

Comment: True, but by clicking once, you can drag your mouse up and down to change the shape.

Comment: I'm sorry Neil Giliomee 1 but it really doesn't work. I let you look at the image I add in the post.

Answer (score 2):

I created a rough remake of your shape

[image]

Start by adding a loop cut as shown

[image]

Add another loop cut here

[image]

The SubSurf modifier will work much better now

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately doesn't work. I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

With the edges selected, Hit CNTRL_+ B and drag to bevel them.

Comment: I tried this method but the bevel doesn't work here. I suppose because edges are not on the same plane.